# Problem 1.3.12 from Hatcher

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let a and b be the generators of $\pi_1$ $(S^1 \vee S^1)$ corresponding to the two $S^1$
summands. Draw a picture of the covering space of $S^1 \vee S^1$
corresponding to the
normal subgroup generated by $a^2$, $b^2$, and $(ab)^4$, and prove that this covering space
is indeed the correct one.

I know the standard way to do this is constructing an octagon, like so, but I was wondering if there are other ways or more interesting ways to do it.
[image]

Comment: The $\LaTeX$ command for the wedge sum is `\vee`: $S^1\vee S^1$ (probably so named because it looks like a "v"). Sadly, `\wedge` goes the wrong way, giving you the smash product: $S^1\wedge S^1$.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: Similiar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3318101